# AngularJS How to manipulate array of objects if each element is stored inside a stand alone directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I've created a custom directive to serve as a template to show some information using `ng-repeat`. I also need to do some manipulation on the array that being looped. My question is how can I remove or add elements to that array, if each element is inside a separate scope inside a stand-alone directive? Without the use of the directive the task is easy:

```
    <div class="well" ng-repeat="dat in data">
        <form novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="dat.name" ng-disabled="enableEdit">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="balance">balance:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="balance" ng-model="dat.balance" ng-disabled="enableEdit">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fruit">favorite Fruit:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fruit" ng-model="dat.favoriteFruit" ng-disabled="enableEdit">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="greeting">greeting:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="greeting" ng-model="dat.greeting" ng-disabled="enableEdit">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove($index)">remove</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="enableEdit=!enableEdit">edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save(dat,$index);enableEdit=!enableEdit" ng-disabled="enableEdit">save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

After the refactoring to directive, the task is not so obvious:

```
    <div class="well" ng-repeat="dat in data">
        <data-directive user="dat" index="{{$index}}" arr="data"></data-directive>
    </div>
```

The directive template looks as follows:

```
<form novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="user.name" ng-disabled="enableEdit">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="balance">balance:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="balance" ng-model="user.balance" ng-disabled="enableEdit">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fruit">favorite Fruit:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fruit" ng-model="user.favoriteFruit" ng-disabled="enableEdit">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="greeting">greeting:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="greeting" ng-model="user.greeting" ng-disabled="enableEdit">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(index)">remove</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="enableEdit=!enableEdit">edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save(user,$index);enableEdit=!enableEdit" ng-disabled="enableEdit">save</button>
</form>
```

Directive js:

```
app.directive("data-directive", ["dataService", function (dataService) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:"directives/dataDirectiveTemplate.html",
        scope:{
            user: "=",
            index: "@",
            arr: "="
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.enableEdit = true;

            $scope.remove = function (index) {
                console.log(arr);
                dataService.removeItem(arr, parseInt(index));
            };

            $scope.save = function (item,index) {
                dataService.saveItem(item, index, $scope.data);

            };

            $scope.changes = function () {
                console.log($scope.data);
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

I managed to pass the `$index` variable, but how do I pass the whole `data` array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Let's first define an owner for `data`. It can be the controller whose view is using `data-directive` or `dataService`.

Now, owner holds `data` and all responsibility to manipulate it.

If it is `dataService`, its method can be called from the directive and `data` is already available with it.

If it is controller it can pass method using `&` e.g.:

```
scope: {
  user: "=",
  index: "@",
  arr: "=",
  onRemove: "&",
  onSave: "&",
  onChange: "&",
},
```